# Adding TFS Build Controller for Collection "A" to a Machine Already Running Agents for Collection "B"

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild

I would like to add a TFS Build Controller for Collection "A" to a machine that is already running build agents for TFS Collection "B". This machine does not have an existing controller for Collection "B", just the agents for Collection "B". Is this possible and/or good practice? I do recall reading that multiple controllers on a machine is not supported, but I don't remember reading anything about this type of scenario.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have discovered that since the Controller is tied to the build service running on the machine, it is not possible to have Agents from one collection (running on that collection's build service) coexist on the same box with a Controller from a different collection (which would require a build service tied to that collection).

Answer (score 0):

Although I don't think I've ever configured it in that manner, I think it should be possible.  In the TFS Admin Console you should be able to go into the properties of each agent and specify the Build Controller, even if it's a different one than the controller installed on that server.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Dylan. Yes, adding the Controller is possible through the TFS admin console, but I am really asking if it's possible without any adverse effects. I'm looking for something more than an anecdotal reply. Can you point me to any documentation for this type of scenario?

Comment: I have since found out it is not possible to do what I was hoping. thanks for taking a look, though.